# MariaDB and node.js on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, mariadb

I have a MAC with MariaDB installed and running.  I have two applications installed,  "Sequel Pro", running native on the MAC, which works and I can connect to the database.  I also have HeidiSQL running under wine, I can also connect and browse the database.

I have also installed node but when I try to connect to the database I cannot connect to the database, the message I'm getting is:

connect ECONNREFUSED then the IP address of my system followed by port 3306

This looks like a permissions problem, but I'm quite new to the MAC and not sure how to resolve the issue.  The scripts running in node.js work on my Windows system.

I know the user exists and is valid and its the same as I use with the SQL applications to connect.

The MAC OSX is running the latest os x sierra, mariadb is version 15.1 distribution 10.1.17 for osx10.12 x64.  node is version 4.6.0

My connection routine:

```
    function mariaDBconnectPrimtive(intIdx, cbRoutine, objParams) {
      try{
        if ( !(mysql && mysql.createPool) ) {
          throw( "Cannot create mysql pool!" );
        }
        var pool;

        if ( intIdx == 1 ) {
          pool = mysqlBusDevPool; 
        } else {
          pool = mysqlPool; 
        }
        if ( pool == undefined ) {
           console.log("strServerHost: " + strServerHost);
           pool = mysql.createPool({host:strServerHost
                          ,port:"3306"
                      ,database:"dbname"
                          ,user:"usrname"
                      ,password:"password"
                      ,timezone:"utc"
            ,multipleStatements:true
                           ,max:1000
                           ,min:1
             ,idleTimeoutMillis:defs.QUERY_TIMEOUT});      
        }
        if ( pool && pool.getConnection ) {  
          pool.getConnection(function(errsts, conn) {
              var resp = {};

              if ( errsts ) {
                resp['error'] = errsts;
                eh.msg({file:strThisFile
                     ,method:"mariaDBconnectPrimtive"
                         ,ex:errsts});
                return;        
              }
              resp['state'] = "connected";

              if ( cbRoutine ) {        
                cbRoutine(conn, resp, objParams);

                if ( conn != undefined ) {
                  conn.release();
                }
             }
          });
        }
        if ( intIdx == 1 ) {
          mysqlBusDevPool = pool; 
        } else {
          mysqlPool = pool; 
        }
      } catch(ex) {
        eh.msg({file:strThisFile
             ,method:"mariaDBconnectPrimtive"
                 ,ex:ex});
      }    
    };
```

Code that is performed when node starts to get the system IP:

```
    os = require("os");
    var objNIs = os.networkInterfaces();        
    for( var strName in objNIs ) {
       var aryIFace = objNIs[strName];
       for( var i=0; i<aryIFace.length; i++ ) {
          var objNI = aryIFace[i];

          if ( objNI['internal'] == false && "IPv4".match(objNI['family']) ) { 
            strServerHost = objNI['address'];
            break; 
          }      
        }
        if ( strServerHost !== undefined ) {
          break;
        }
      }
```

It seems to be something to do with the IP address that is returned, I hard coded the server address to be "localhost" and it works, but whats wrong with the I/P that is assigned to the system?

I created a user in mariadb with permission to access the original I/P but this didn't help.

Comment: check your firewall and security settings of macOs.

Comment: The firewall is off which is the default setting, and why would desktop applications be able to connect but not node in the terminal?

Comment: Can you post your connection code....what if you change the ip by something like localhost or 127.0.01

Comment: I will amend my post to include the connection code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't connect by IP-address is documented [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/):

> MariaDB packages bind MariaDB to 127.0.0.1 (the loopback IP address) by default...

Which means it's only accessibly through the loopback interface, and not any other interfaces that may allow external IP-traffic (like the one that is associated with the IP-address that your code is resolving to).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, as mentioned before this works on the same setup on Windows, there is no remote access, the client and the server are one in the same.

Comment: @SPlatten localhost/127.0.0.1, at least on Unix, is handled by a different network interface than the one handling the external IP-number of the server. MariaDB, by default, only listens on the interface that handles localhost, so you _specifically_ need to use _"localhost"_ or _"127.0.0.1"_ to connect to it.

Comment: Try `/usr/local/etc`